# Python - How to combine the rows into a single row in Pandas? (not group by)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a weird dataframe using Pandas:

```
print(df)

Active        Dead       Hold
Product1      n/a        n/a
n/a           Product2   n/a
n/a           n/a        Product3
```

I want to combine the three rows into 1 row and the expected output is:

```
Active        Dead       Hold
Product1      Product2   Product3
```

I really don't know how to do this and appreciate your help! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one slightly faster alternative:

```
new = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that dropping `NaN` from each column of the df yields the same number of rows for each column, you can loop through each column of the df, drop `NaN`, and place them in a new DataFrame.

```
df_collapsed = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
    df_collapsed[col] = df[col].dropna().values
```

Output:

```
df_collapsed

     Active      Dead      Hold
0  Product1  Product2  Product3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!